# Changing webdav password remotely

Tags: php, webdav

I've slowly been working on a PHP client for WebDAV. I want to add a feature to change the password. I'm not even sure this is possible, but I thought someone else might know. So, is it possible, and if so, how can I go about doing it? I don't really need the exact code, mostly just what headers/content I need to send.